# Scala different outputs of logically same programs

Tags: scala

```
val a = List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
val b = a.grouped(2).filter(_.length == 2).map(x => (x(0), x(1)))

//b.foreach(x => println(x))

val r = b.foldLeft((0, 0)) { 
    case ((m, n), (x, y)) => {
        (m + x, n + y) 
    }
}

println(r)
```

The program gives correct output (4, 6) for the above program. But when I uncomment the foreach statement above it outputs (0, 0). What's wrong here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`val b = a.grouped(2).filter(_.length == 2).map(x => (x(0), x(1)))`, `b`'s type is `Iterator`:

```
scala> :type b
Iterator[(Int, Int)]
```

so when you have iterated `b` by `b.foreach(x => println(x))`, after this the current iterator `b` is empty, Since `Iterator` only can be iterated once.